# change number of gray levels in a grayscale image in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am rather new to matlab, but I was hoping someone could help with this question. So I have a color image that I want to convert to grayscale and then reduce the number of gray levels. So I read in the image and I used rgb2gray() to convert the image to grayscale. However, I am not sure how to convert the image to use only 32 gray levels instead of 255 gray levels.

I was trying to use colormap(gray(32)), but this seemed to have no effect on the plotted image itself or the colorbar under the image. So I was not sure where else to look. Any tips out there? Thanks.

Comment: You really don't want to further quantize it by simply picking the levels in intervals of 8 colors. Consider using the improved grayscale quantization method.

Answer (score 3):

While `result = (img/8)*8` does convert a grayscale image in the range [0, 255] to a subset of that range but now using only 32 values, it might create undesirable artifacts. A method that possibly produces visually better images is called Improved Grayscale Quantization (abbreviated as IGS). The pseudo-code for performing it can be given as:

```
mult = 256 / (2^bits)
mask = 2^(8 - bits) - 1
prev_sum = 0
for x = 1 to width
    for y = 1 to height
        value = img[x, y]
        if value >> bits != mask:
            prev_sum = value + (prev_sum & mask)
        else:
            prev_sum = value
        res[x, y] = (prev_sum >> (8 - bits)) * mult
```

As an example, consider the following figure and the respective quantizations with `bits = 5`, `bits = 4`, and `bits = 3` using the method above:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Now the same images but quantized by doing `(img/(256/(2^bits)))*(256/(2^bits))`:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

This is not a pathological example.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the number of different values in an image by simple rounding:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('image.gif'));
J = 8*round(I/8)
```

See `imhist(I)` and `imhist(J)` for the effect.

However, if you want to reduce image size, you might be better off using an image processing program like Photoshop, Gimp or IrfanView and save as a 32 color gif. In that way you'll actually reduce the file's palette, and I think that's something Matlab can't do.

Comment: Be careful with `round`. You will end up with 33 gray levels if `I` is not of integer type. If `I` is of integer type, you don't need any `round`. ;-)

Comment: @s.bandara: Good point about rounding. Also it appears the OP might actually be looking for `imwrite`, using an appropriate map, but I don't have the time to figure it out now.

Comment: @Junuxx are you aware of how bad the resulting image will potentially look with this procedure ? (I commented this on your answer simply because it appeared at top when I visited this question, but this is equally valid for the other answers present here.)

Comment: @mmgp: What do you recommend? Doing histogram equalization first?

Comment: @Junuxx a method called improved grayscale quantization commonly provides better results, I might include an answer using it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the the type of your image data is `uint8` which I would suspect. If that's the case divide the image by 8 to abuse the flooring effect of integer division, multiply with 8 again, and you're set: `I2=(I/8)*8`. `I2` will have only 32 gray levels.